Neo4j Warning: UnknownPropertyKeyWarning for Existing Property
I'm encountering a Neo.ClientNotification.Statement.UnknownPropertyKeyWarning in my Neo4j query, despite confirming that the property embeddings exists on my Asset nodes.
I have 31 Asset nodes, and each node has an embeddings property with dimensions of 768. The property is confirmed to be non-null for all nodes.

class Neo4jGraph:

    ...

    def best_matches(self, embedding: List[float], limit: int = 10) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:

        query = """
        WITH $embedding AS input_embedding
        MATCH (a:Asset)
        WHERE a.embeddings IS NOT NULL
        RETURN a.id AS id, a.url AS url, a.description AS description, vector.similarity.cosine(input_embedding, a.embeddings) AS similarity
        ORDER BY similarity DESC
        LIMIT $limit
        """

        with self.driver.session() as session:

            result = session.run(query, embedding = embedding, limit = limit)
            assets = []

            for record in result:
                assets.append({
                    'asset_id': record['id'],
                    'asset_url': record['url'],
                    'description': record['description'],
                    'similarity': record['similarity'],
                    'asset_tags': record['tags']
                })

            return assets

When running the above python code, I encounter the following error:

Received notification from DBMS server: {severity: WARNING} {code:
Neo.ClientNotification.Statement.UnknownPropertyKeyWarning} {category:
UNRECOGNIZED} {title: The provided property key is not in the
database} {description: One of the property names in your query is not
available in the database, make sure you didn't misspell it or that
the label is available when you run this statement in your application
(the missing property name is: embeddings)} {position: line: 4,
column: 17, offset: 84}

I want to understand why am I receiving this warning when the property exists and is valid? Whereas running the same cypher query in Neo4j Desktop works fine.

Which version of Neo4j are you using?

Enterprise edition v5.20.0

I'm getting a similiar issue, python 3.12, neo4j-python v 5.25.0, neo4j 5.24.
Cypher runs fine in browser but get this error for some (not all) cypher queries executed via python,

@AmitPathak I resolved the issue my side, there was a typo in the driver.execute_query parameters:
    with neo4j.GraphDatabase.driver(URI, auth=AUTH) as driver:
        records, summary, keys = driver.execute_query(gql, database_=DB)

I had "database=DB" not "database_=DB"
It could be something simple your side, where session is pointing to the wrong database (neo4j default, not a specific database)

Make sure you are pointing to the same database in python as well as the driver:
DB = "<your DB consistent with the one you're executing against in browser>"

with neo4j.GraphDatabase.driver(URI, auth=AUTH) as driver:
   with driver.session(database=DB) as session:
      session.run(query)


